# PHP based Web Applications vs CGI

Tags: php, web-applications

I've been working with Java webapps for quite sometime now. I was wondering how PHP based webapps are different from Java based ones. I could find some differences about security, availability of libraries etc.,

Basically, Java (servlet) based webapps are multi-threaded environments, where by a single process caters to the needs of different requests. How does this work in PHP?

a) Is every request a single process? In such a case how can we ensure memory utilization and other shared resources are under control?

b) Is there a concept called application scope/singleton in PHP based webapps?

c) Can we have connection pools?

Basically, how is PHP different from CGI?

The question might sound silly for PHP developers. I'll be happy to know there is already a place where the differences are documented. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Java web applications are hosted (i.e. run within) a stateful, long-running Java process; because of this you can take advantage of in-memory object caching and the ability to manipulate threads.

The standard CGI model (ignoring FastCGI for now) is considerably simpler: a process is started and is passed the incoming HTTP request. The CGI process handles the request itself (including the creation of its own threads, if necessary) and then returns the HTTP response to the process that spawned the child CGI process. The CGI process is then terminated - so anything kept in-memory is lost and has to be serialized to some kind of persistance medium such as a database or file on disk.

(Speculation: CGI's design probably has to do with limited resources available on servers in the early 1990s, and how websites weren't visited all that often so it didn't make sense to use memory like that; finally if you're working on a huge scalable project then you probably won't be interested in in-memory caching because you'll have a dedicated state server).

PHP is a CGI system, so it inherits the limitations of the "one server process per request" model - as for not supporting threads: it seems to be a conscious decision of PHP's developers because it vastly simplifies the system (no need to worry about synchronisation, for example, and because PHP is probably the number one "beginner's language" nowadays it makes sense not to give them enough rope to hang themselves) - besides if you need to use multi-threading in a webserving scenario then PHP is probably the wrong tool to use in the first place.

PHP is not different to CGI - PHP implements CGI. Java webservers do not use CGI (at least not to serve Java applications, and note that there do exist CGI implementations of Java servlet hosts, but let's not complicate things).

Because PHP is not stateful it means it can't pool connections - but in practice this isn't a problem. When you pair PHP with MySQL you'll find that operations are surprisingly cheap. You can connect to a database, grab some data from a SELECT, and return a nicely formatted HTML table all in under 5ms even on a decade-old machine. It doesn't matter what platform you use so long as page generation times are kept under 30ms (my personal objective time limit for a good user experience).

Comment: While PHP can be used via CGI, it isn't normally. mod_php is the usual way to interface between a web server and a PHP programme.

Comment: `mod_php` is only for Apache. Other servers like IIS, lighthttpd, etc don't use that. There are also ISAPI builds. However regardless of which web-server API you use PHP is still stateless so it can conform to the lowest-common-functionality provided by CGI.

Comment: @Quentin..Is mod_php philosophically different from CGI? Like it is still one process per request/no inherent support for connection pooling etc..rite?

Comment: @Gopal with `mod_php` a PHP script runs within the Apache process, but still under a single thread. Use of `mod_php` is not recommended because it makes it harder to isolate and sandbox websites from each other: http://php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php

Comment: @Dai..thanks for the quick response. Can you throw some light on how are PHP based webapps throttled? Like if there are multiple requests coming in a flood, how does PHP scale. Memory, DB connections and CPU will be an issue here. Also, if we have multiple nodes, how is session shared? Like Tomcat and JBoss, do we have any support for cluster?

Comment: @Gopal : You can scale PHP with ZendServer/ZendCluster.Zend server is full application server, it has thread pools, connection pol, etc. Read more info on www.zend.com